How to use all argument constructor for a JOOQ POJO with identity column?
I have a table like below
create TABLE google_co2_emission_data (
    departure text NOT NULL,
    arrival text NOT NULL,
);

alter table google_co2_emission_data
    add column co2_data_id bigint generated always as identity primary key;

Is there a way I can use the all-argument constructor for the generated POJO like below?
new GoogleCo2EmissionData("abc", "def", ??)`

Database - Postgres 14.4

I don't understand this question. Why couldn't you use the all-argument constructor? Or do you mean you want to omit arguments from the constructor?

I am using GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY column with postgres. If I attempt to add some value then postgres will throw an error. In this case is there a way for me to omit the last argument in the constructor? I prefer to use the constructor while creating the POJOs over setters so that in future if some fields are added in the schema then it throws the compilation error in the codegen stage itself, and the developer is forced to look into the new field in the code.

Reference link for GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY

I understand you'd like to avoid passing any argument value to that parameter, but Java doesn't have named / defaulted parameters, so there's no way to omit that value in your constructor call. Just pass null instead, or use the default constructor and the setters for those columns that you do care about.
new GoogleCo2EmissionData("abc", "def", null);
var pojo = new GoogleCo2EmissionData();
pojo.setDeparture("abc");
pojo.setArrival("def");

